# ActionFactory.SAVE in a ViewPart

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

My application have an Editor and some View extend ViewPart. In the Editor I can create a Save action like this

```
Action action = (Action) ActionFactory.SAVE.create(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow());
```

and the add action in a ToolBar. I can control this SAVE action by Override `isDirty()` and `doSave()` method. And my question is:

1. Can I add a SAVE ActionFactory in a ViewPart?
2. How can I Override SAVE method in ViewPart?
3. Is there any other way to do it?

My View look like this:

```
    GridLayout layoutProperties = new GridLayout(2, false);
    layoutProperties.marginHeight = 0;
    layoutProperties.marginWidth = 0;
    propertiesVersion.setLayout(layoutProperties);
    propertiesVersion.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1));

    toolkitProperties = new FormToolkit(propertiesVersion.getDisplay());
    sectionProperties = toolkitProperties.createSection(propertiesVersion, Section.TITLE_BAR);
    sectionProperties.setText("Version Properties");
    sectionProperties.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 2, 0));
    //some Label and Text here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an RCP you normally create the Save action in your `ActionBarAdvisor` with something like:

```java
@Override
protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) 
{
  saveAction = ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window);
  register(saveAction);

  ... more ...
}
```

The save action will then work with any part that implements `ISaveablePart`, it is this interface that defines `isDirty`, `doSave`, ... So if you implement this in your view part you will get save support.

Comment: After spend a morning with google I found out a way just seem like your. Any thank you for your answer. I will mark this as a correct answer.